Add type constraints on generic class that extends a parent and implements interfaces
In the class hierarchy below, how to define type constraint for T (where T : class, new())?
abstract class AbstractComponent<T> : Parent, IComponentType, IRelationship
{}

class ChildComponent : AbstractComponent<CarComponent>
{}


What stopped you from adding where T : class, new()?

your problem is pretty unclear. where T: class, new() should compile just fine, so where exactly is your problem? Seems like you want some different constraint. Probably something with Parent?

It's not clear what you mean by

In the class hierarchy below, how to define type constraint for T (where T : class, new())?

while you could simply add where T : class, new() but if you having trouble with figuring out where to put where T : class, new() it should be something like this:
abstract class AbstractComponent<T> : Parent, IComponentType, IRelationship
where T : class, new() {}

